# How to share the value of a field between 2 yup schemas

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm building a multi-step form where each step is its own form and has its own validation schema. im using react-hook-form for the form (don't think that matters here) and yup for the validation so heres a simplified version of what im trying to do

```
export const page1Schema = yup.object().shape({
  ["signature"]: yup.string().required(),
});

export const page2Schema = yup.object().shape({
  ["dependentField"]: yup.string().when(["signature"], {
    is: (signature) => signature !== "",
    then: () => yup.string().required(),
    otherwise: () => yup.string().notRequired(),
  })
});
```

so in page2Schema i want to access the value of the field 'signature' which is in step 1 of the form and set the field to required only if field in step 1 meets some condition. is there a way to do this?

Comment: For that to happen, it should be combined at a point to get validated together. When you do so, you can use `this.parent()` method in `test()` to get 1 step above in object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this :

```
export const page2Schema = yup.object().shape({
   dependentField: yup.string()
               .test("Dependent field is required when signature is provided", 
                     function (value) {
                        //const signature = this.resolve(yup.ref("signature"));
                          const signature = this.parent.signature;
                             if (signature) {
                                return !!value;
                             } else {
                                return true;
                             }
                     }),
              }).
```

In the this.resolve() function, you can get the value of the `signature`.

If `signature` is true, can check whether `dependentField` has a value(`!!value`).

If `signature` is false, this field is not provided and can allow any value for `dependentField`.

Comment: i just tried this but signature is undefined

Comment: please check my updated code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try to solve my problem but to make this work i would have to combine the schemas at some point like @Hiren F commented, i was trying to avoid doing that. if i cant find a better solution then ill do this approach of this.parent

Comment: I hope your success in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to get around this problem in a case where i can get the value from inside the form and pass it in to the schema

Solution 1:
changing the schema to a function

```
export const page1Schema = (value) => yup.object().shape({
  ["signature"]: yup.string().required(),
});
```

and pass in the prop `resolver: yupResolver(page1Schema(value))`

Solution 2:
using context

```
export const page2Schema = yup.object().shape({
  ["dependentField"]: yup.string().when(["$signature"], {
    is: (signature) => signature !== "",
    then: () => yup.string().required(),
    otherwise: () => yup.string().notRequired(),
  })
});
```

then to pass the context using rhf

```
const {} =useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(page1Schema),
  context: { signature: reduxState.signature}
});
```

Note: both of these solutions do not solve the problem completely but in my case im using redux toolkit to hold all the form values so i can pass to the context the value of the field from form 1 (signature) to page2Schema